# Wrong update in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

Update query works, but not properly.

What is the problem?

```
UPDATE Orders
SET discount = 10
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT C.discount 
              FROM Orders AS C
              JOIN OrderItems AS O ON C.orderID = O.orderID
              WHERE (C.dateOrder BETWEEN '01.07.2013' AND GETDATE()) 
              GROUP BY C.discount
              HAVING COUNT(O.orderID) > 1)
```

That in itself works

```
SELECT C.discount 
FROM Orders AS C 
JOIN OrderItems AS O ON C.orderID = O.orderID
WHERE (C.dateOrder BETWEEN '01.07.2013' AND GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY C.discount
HAVING COUNT(O.orderID) > 1
```

And the result is correct

Comment: What does "not properly" actually mean?

Comment: You don't appear to reference the table you updating in your exists clause...

Comment: We don't know what you are trying to achieve, so you need to explain that so we understand how its not working.

Comment: The query displays 2 columns. The update updates the entire table

Comment: So please show some sample data, and your expected results. And also try and explain in words e.g. "I want to update all orders with a discount and with more than one order line to have a new discount of 10%".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might do what you want - but without understanding exactly what you are trying to do I am guessing.

```
UPDATE C SET
  discount = 10
FROM ORDERS C
WHERE C.dateOrder between '01.07.2013' and GETDATE()
-- Updating only orders with an existing discount
AND C.discount IS NOT NULL
-- And with more than 1 order line
AND (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM OrderItems AS O 
  WHERE O.orderID = C.orderID
) > 1
```